# Undefined variable in CodeIgniter view using submit function

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, view, undefined

I'm trying create a website using codeigniter. The structure that I use is only using view and controller. The model is directly in controller.

So, i got this error message:

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: view

Filename: template/default.php

Line Number: 146
```

And this is my code on controller (artikeladmin.php)

```
public function add()
    {
        if($this->input->post())
        {
            $judul = $this->input->post('judul');
            $kategori_id = $this->input->post('kategori_id');
            $tanggal = $this->input->post('tanggal');
            $gambar = $this->input->post('gambar');
            $published = $this->input->post('published');
            $deskripsi = $this->input->post('deskripsi');



            $config['upload_path'] ='assets/images/upload/';
            $config['allowed_types'] ='jpeg|png|gif|jpg';
            $config['max_size'] ='*';
            $config['max_width'] ='*';
            $config['max_height'] ='*';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if(!$this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                $data['error'] = array('error' =>$this->upload->display_errors());
                $this->load->view('admin/template/default', $data);
            }
            else
            {
            $attr = $this->upload->data();
            $args = array(
                'gambar'    => $attr['file_name'],
                'kategori_id'   => $kategori_id,
                'judul'     => $judul,
                'published' => $published,
                'tanggal'   => $tanggal,
                'deskripsi' => $deskripsi

        );

            $this->db->insert('artikel', $args);            
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Data berhasil disimpan');
            redirect('artikeladmin');
        }

        }
        $user = $this->session->userdata('myuser');
        if(!isset($user) or empty($user))
        redirect('login');

        $sql = " SELECT * FROM kategori";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $kategori = $query->result_array();

        $data['view'] = 'admin/add_article';
        $data['kategori'] = $kategori;
        $data['action'] = 'artikeladmin/add/';
        $this->load->view('admin/template/default', $data);
    }
```

And this is my view (template/default.php)

```
<div id="content" class="span10">
         <?php $this->load->view($view); ?> 
        </div>
```

in my controller you can see that i have define variable view like this

`$data['view'] = 'admin/add_article';`

And im trying to add new variable like

`$data['view'] = $data;`

but the error still happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `do_upload()` fails it will load the view without the `$view` variable being set:

```
if(!$this->upload->do_upload())
{
    $data['error'] = array('error' =>$this->upload->display_errors());
    $this->load->view('admin/template/default', $data);
}
```

`default.php` looks for `$view`

```
<?php $this->load->view($view); ?>
```

and you get the Undefined variable error.

Try instantiating `$view` before any calls to `default.php` are made.